# Create 2d tensor of points using tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to make a tensor with all the points between a certain range.
For example

```
min_x = 5
max_x = 7

min_y = 3
max_y = 5

points = get_points(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y)

print(point) # [[5, 3], [5, 4], [5, 5], [6, 3], [6, 4], [6, 5], [7, 3], [7, 4], [7, 5]]
```

I'm trying to do this inside a tensorflow function. AKA @tf.function

Also all the inputs to get_points need to be tensors.

Thanks, I'm new to tensorflow as you can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.meshgrid`, then stack `x` and `y` along the last dim after reshaping these two tensors.

```py
min_x = 5
max_x = 7

min_y = 3
max_y = 5

def get_points(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y):
    x, y = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(min_x, max_x+1),tf.range(min_y, max_y+1))

    _x = tf.reshape(x, (-1,1))
    _y = tf.reshape(y, (-1,1))

    return tf.squeeze(tf.stack([_x, _y], axis=-1))

res = get_points(min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y)
K.eval(res)
# array([[5, 3],
#        [6, 3],
#        [7, 3],
#        [5, 4],
#        [6, 4],
#        [7, 4],
#        [5, 5],
#        [6, 5],
#        [7, 5]], dtype=int32)
```